# What is the mistake I am making in the below C# code?

Tags: c#, oop

I have an interface like

```
interface IEmpDeptRepository : IEmployeeRepository,IDepartmentRepository
 {
        IEnumerable<EmpDept> GetAll();        
 }

interface IEmployeeRepository
{
        IEnumerable<Employee> GetAll();       
}

interface IDepartmentRepository
{
        IEnumerable<Department> GetAll();        
}
```

The Class **EmpDept** is

```
 class EmpDept 
        {
            public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
            public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }    
        }
```

Now the class **EmpDeptRepository** is as under

```
 public class EmpDeptRepository:IEmpDeptRepository
    {
        private List<EmpDept> empDepts = new List<EmpDept>();

        public EmpDeptRepository()
        {

            Add(new EmpDept { Employees = IEmployeeRepository.GetAll(), Departments = IDepartmentRepository.GetAll() });            
        }

        public EmpDept Add(EmpDept empDept)
        {
            if (empDept == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Employee Department");
            }            
            empDepts.Add(empDept);
            return empDept;
        }


        public IEnumerable<EmpDept> GetAll()
        {
            return empDepts;
        }

        IEnumerable<Employee> IEmployeeRepository.GetAll()
        {
            IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository();
            return employeeRepository.GetAll();
        }

        IEnumerable<Department> IDepartmentRepository.GetAll()
        {
            IDepartmentRepository deptRepository = new DepartmentRepository();
            return deptRepository.GetAll();
        }
    }
```

And I am getting the below error

```
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Models.EmpDept' is less accessible than method 'Models.EmpDeptRepository.Add(Models.EmpDept)'
Error   2   Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'Models.EmpDept' is less accessible than method 'Models.EmpDeptRepository.Add(Models.EmpDept)'
Error   3   Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.EmpDept>' is less accessible than method 'Models.EmpDeptRepository.GetAll()'
```

What mistake am I making?

Comment: yes Priyanka change `class EmpDept ` to `public class EmpDept `. It will resolve the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all your classes public:

```
public class EmpDept
```

Comment: my all classes are public only...

Comment: `class EmpDept` =>  `public class EmpDept`

Comment: thanks that worked. now another problem. for the line  Add(new EmpDept { Employees = IEmployeeRepository.GetAll(), Departments = IDepartmentRepository.GetAll() });  , error: Error 2 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'IEmployeeRepository.GetAll()' 
Error 3 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'IDepartmentRepository.GetAll()'

Comment: As the message says: you can't access `GetAll()` through the interface. You need an instance. i.e. `this.GetAll()` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Make class EmpDept public, because when you want to access it with public methods it has to be public too.